# VoiceOver reads table header twice and always adds the word "heading"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return self.setupFriendsHeaderView()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.accessibilityTraits = .none
    for subView in view.subviews {
        subView.accessibilityTraits = .none
    }
}

func setupFriendsHeaderView() -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: 44)))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.switchPendingRequestsStatus)))
    view.isAccessibilityElement = true
    view.accessibilityLabel = "Pending requests"

    return view
}
```

When you tap the header first time VoiceOver says: "Pending requests. Pending requests header." Sometimes it doesn't manage to finish the first sentence and starts speaking the next one. The second time it just says "Pending requests header." What I need it to do is say "Pending requests" once, and no word "heading".
I saw the answer recommending to use `willDisplayHeaderView` method, but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, I ended up implementing it as a separate view above the table view. I'm not sure I need to close the issue, since I either don't understand something fundamental, which someone might yet explain to me here, or it's a VO bug I should post to Apple if more people experience the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display a table view with section headers using VoiceOver never saying "header", just forget it: that's a dead end ⟹ there's currently **no solution** to complete this kind of table view design.

The best way to get your technical purpose is to **create a single table view whose section headers are single cells with a different appearance** ⟹ I specified "technical" because, functionally, that's definitely neither appropriate nor [recommended](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html#title-and-header) for the VoiceOver users.

Indeed, the section headers are important markers that not only delimit specific blocks of information but also allow 
to move very quickly from one section to another thanks to the rotor.

I guess your purpose might be purely visual because, functionally speaking, it **can't be approved by any accessibility experts or VoiceOver users**.

As you did, I spent a lot of time to try and find a technical solution for this "problem" but, even if I found it *(unfortunately I didn't)*, I would never have implemented it for sure.

==========  **EDIT**  ==========

After your comment *(07.25.2019)*, I now understand that your problem is the title that is read twice and not the will of removing the 'header' trait.

I created a blank project where I implemented the code snippet hereunder to get a tableview with headers that are never repeated twice:

```
class SimpleHeadersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 4 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 5 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero,
                                              size: CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width,
                                                           height: 44)))

        let a11yHeader = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: headerView)
        a11yHeader.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = headerView.frame

        a11yHeader.isAccessibilityElement = true
        a11yHeader.accessibilityLabel = "Pending requests"
        a11yHeader.accessibilityTraits = .header

        headerView.accessibilityElements = [a11yHeader]

        return headerView
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId",
                                                 for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Try this out and adapt it to your application.

Now, **VoiceOver reads table header once and always adds the word “heading”**.

Comment: The problem isn't that VO reads the the word "header", it's that it reads the title twice - once with the work header, and once without. You are correct in saying I shouldn't remove the word "header", but I definitely don't need the title to be read twice.

Comment: @f3dm76: you wrote 'What I need it to do is say "Pending requests" once, and no word "heading"' that mislead my understanding. See the EDIT answer in my post and tell me if it suits you.

Comment: @f3dm76 Have you found any solution yet where `heading` word is not spoken for table header ?

Comment: I ended up moving this element so that it is not a table header anymore (moved it to table.headerView). The thing is it's not a header per se, it's more of a button which should scroll together with the table (That is the reason I wanted to remove the word "header"). 
The repetition was happening because the header contained a button which when tapped reloaded the section of a table containing this very button. That was too much for VO, and it read it once after tapping the button and once more after reloading, thinking it's the new element needing announcement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind of announcing "Heading" is that `UITableView` adds `header` trait to the header views. To avoid this just simply subclass from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and override `accessibilityTraits` with empty traits like this:

```
override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
  get { [] }
  set { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` with a custom UILabel. I found that setting the `accessibilityLabel` of the headerfooterview to the text of this custom label fixed the problem.